# 500 Internal Server Error with Guzzlehttp in laravel

Tags: laravel, sap-business-one-di-api

I am developing a project where I am saving master data to SAP Business One. I can receive the data locally and I want to send it to the handle with a button. When I click the button I get this error

[image]

codes as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Znt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iqXX.png)

Comment: We need a bit more content to help you with that. What code throws the error? What data do you want to send? And so on.

Comment: ı want to print business partner master data to SAP

Comment: Please provide the Code as Snippets in your Question, its not proper to add Screenshots of that and makes it hard to help you with that.